# Creating a new schema LDAP with ApacheDS

Tags: apache, ldap, apacheds

I currently working on creating a custom attribute therefore with the use of Apache Directory Studio I have created a new schema project, new schema, new attribute and
new Object class.

(used this guide)
https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.1-adding-schema-elements.html

I then export my new schema and finally import into my Root DSE (which is located on a virtual machine ubunutu).

The guide then tell:

> You must restart the server if you want to use the added
> AttributeTypes or ObjectClasses. The schema is currently not dynamic
> in ApacheDS

And it is here the error occurs:

What it  says is that:

> ERR_13215_VALUE_EXPECT_STRING The value is expected to be a String
>
> ERR_16009_LDIF_LOAD_FAIL Failed to load schema LDIF file cn=sevenseas.ldif
>
> org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapInvalidAttributeValueException: ERR_13215_VALUE_EXPECT_STRING The value is expected to be a String

What am I missing? I have followed the guide each and every step.

added screenshot of the whole stack trace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. This is what I did to solve the problem:
In the schema directory of the LDAP server instance I found and opened cn=mycustomschema.ldif and changed 
creatorsname:: ... (2 lines of b64)
into:
creatorsname: uid=admin,ou=system